# http call in backbone promise

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, foreach, promise

Hi I have a backbone web app using Jquery and NodeJs/mongo as the server side framework. I'm having problems with making a http get call with a foreah loop and the results of the get call being iteratively added to each row of the loop.

```
                        var eventid = this.model.get("_id");

         var inPromise = $.get("/registrants/list?eventid="+eventid,null,null,"json").then(
            function (result){

                var temp;
                var finalVal = '';
                var tempfinalVal = "";
                var loop = 0
                    percentage = 0;

                $.each(result.registrants,function(index,registrant){
                    temp =    JSON.parse(registrant.fields);

                    for (var key in temp) {

                        if(key =="Email"){

                           if(temp[key] != ""){
                                $.get("/stats/registrant?userid="+temp[key]+"&eventid="+eventid,null,null,"json").then(function(result2){

                                    percentage = (result2.Stats.type ===undefined || result2.Stats.type ==null) ? "0": result2.Stats.type;

                                    finalVal +=percentage+"\n";


                                }).fail(function(){

                                    percentage = "0";
                                });
                            }

                        }else if(key =="eventid"){    

                            loop++;
                            finalVal = finalVal.slice(0, - 1);
                            finalVal +='\n';

                        } 

                        finalVal +=temp[key] + ',';


                    }


                });

                //promises.push(inPromise);

            }
        ).done(function(finalVal){

            $("#webcast-download-registrants-tn").attr("href",'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;filename=registration.csv",'+encodeURIComponent(finalVal));

                console.log("DONE");
        }).fail(function(){
                console.log("fail");
        });


       // promise.done(function () {
       //                  console.log(" PROMISE DONE");
       // });
```

So I have the loop through a collection  and the last item of the docuemnt gets a content froma nother http call and when all is fone it will create a CSV file. The problem is that THE "DONE" text echos firts then the "CALL" text is displayed

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you want to end up with please?

Comment: firstname, lastname, email,company,score
bob,doe,bdoe@zuryahoo.com,Company A, 50%
jane,doe,jdoe@zuryahoo.com,Company B, 30%
john,doe,jdoe@zuryahoo.com,Company F, 65% 

With the percntage coming from a different collection

Comment: Mmm, more questions I'm afraid. (i) presumably 'firstname','lastname', 'email' and 'company' are all delivered as properties of `registrant.fields`? (ii) what are the "\n" characters for? and (iii) why the need to `slice()` for the 'eventid' field?

Comment: Also, are you sure this is Node/backbone? It looks very much like Browser/jQuery.

Comment: The front end is backbone/jquery the server side is Nodejs. The SLICE is simlply to take the last comma from the line, the "\n" chars are the actual values and yest the titles (firstname, lastaname etc) come from registrant.fields, they are the vars' key

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now. See answer below.

Comment: Thanks for that with, it worked with some minor tweeking of how I want the CSV lines to display but essentially it worked.

Comment: Excellent! I hope you liked the `$.when.apply(...)` with its double nested .joins. That's the bit I had to test.

Comment: Yeah its good, I had tried the apply() but couldn't get it to work, previously, but youway does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick, your problem is not the simplest due to :

- the need for nested asynchronous gets
- the need to build each CSV data row partly synchronously, partly asynchronously.
- the need for a mechanism to handle the fulfilment of multiple promises generated in the inner loop.

From what you've tried, I guess you already know that much.

One important thing to note is that you can't rely on `for (var key in temp)` to deliver properties in any particular order. Only arrays have order.

You might try something like this :

```
var url = "/stats/registrant",
    data = { 'eventid': this.model.get('_id') },
    rowTerminator = "\n",
    fieldNames = ['firstname','lastname','email','company','score'];

function getScore(email) {
    return $.get(url, $.extend({}, data, {'userid':email}), null, "json").then(function(res) {
        return res.Stats ? res.Stats.type || 0 : 0;
    }, function() {
        //ajax failure - assume score == 0
        return $.when(0);
    });
}

$.get("/registrants/list", data, null, "json").then(function(result) {
    var promises = [];//An array in which to accumulate promises of CSV rows

    promises.push($.when(fieldNames)); //promise of CSV header row

    if(result.registrants) {
        $.each(result.registrants, function(index, registrant) {
            if(registrant.fields) {
                // Synchronously initialize row with firstname, lastname, email and company 
                // (omitting score for now).
                var row = fieldNames.slice(0,-1).map(function(fieldName, i) {
                    return registrant.fields[fieldName] || '';
                });
                //`row` remains available to inner functions due to closure

                var promise;
                if(registrant.fields.Email) {
                    // Fetch the registrant's score ...
                    promise = getScore(registrant.fields.Email).then(function(score) {
                        //... and asynchronously push the score onto row
                        row.push(score);
                        return row;
                    });
                } else {
                    //or synchronously push zero onto row ...
                    row.push(0);
                    //... and create a resolved promise
                    promise = $.when(row);
                }
                promises.push(promise);//Accumulate promises of CSV data rows (still in array form), in the correct order.
            }
        });
    }
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        //Join all the pieces, in nested arrays, together into one long string.
        return [].slice.apply(arguments).map(function(row) {
            return row.join(); //default glue is ','
        }).join(rowTerminator);
    });
}).done(function(str) {
    $("#webcast-download-registrants-tn").attr("href",'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;filename=registration.csv",'+encodeURIComponent(str));
    console.log("DONE");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

*partially tested*

See comments in code for explanation and please ask if there's anything you don't follow.